# PHP array_push() inside a function in a class to array outside of class

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, loops

I'm struggling with my lack of operational knowledge with handling or arrays and variables within a private function that is within a class in an applciation I've "inherited" control of.

The function loops for X days, within that loop, a certain number of MySQL rows will be returned, from a range of different queries. Each row from each query issues a +1 to a counter.

Some maths is then performed on the value of the counter (not really relevant)

Once X days have been iterated through, I need to discard all days calcualted coutner value EXCEPT the value that was the highest. I had planned on using `max($array);` for this.

I will greatly strip down the code for the purpose of this example:

```
class Calendar {

   public $heights;

   private fucntion dayLoop($cellNumber) {
      $heights = []; //array
      $block_count = 0; //counter
         while(mysqlrowdata) {
           [code for mysql operations]
           $block_count++; //increment the count 
         }
      $day_height = ($block_count * 16) + 18; //do some math specific to my application
      $this->heights[] = $day_height; //commit calc'd value to array
      //array_push($heights, $day_height); //this was a previosu attempt, i dont think i should use array_push here..??
   }
}
```

This function is called on other "front end" pages, and if I perform a `var_dump($heights);` at the bottom of one of those pages, the array returns empty with

> Array ( )

Essentially, at that front end page, **I need to be able to A) inspect the array with vlaues from each looped day from X days, and B) pull the largest calc'd counter value from any of the X days that were iterated through in the loop.**

I have tried a myriad of things, like changing the function to be public, defining the start of the array on the front end pages instead of anywhere in the class or fucntion. I declared array name as a variabel in the class as I read that I needed to do that.

Overall, I just don't really understand how I'm MEANT to be handling this, or if I'm going about it in completely the wrong way? Solutions very welcome, but advice and words of wisdom also appreciated greatly. Thanks.

Comment: Put some real code in there. Your sample is too simple to figure out what you really want.

Comment: Did you check that the array actually gets a value in the method? Did you do `var_dump($heights);` or `var_dump($calendar->heights();`?

Comment: @ishegg I tested with var_dump($heights) as well as print_r($heights); within the loop itself and it does NOT add a value to the array. It prints "array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }" to page for the number of iterated days

Comment: Notice that `$this->heights` is different than `$heights`. One is your instance attribute, the other is an empty array you init'ed in the method and never modified.

Comment: @ishegg           
$day_height = ($block_count * 16) + 18;
$this->heights[] = $day_height;
var_dump($this->$heights);
returns "NULL NULL NULL" on screen